# What's the meaning of "offhand" in this dialogue?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> “Obi-Wan!” he shouted to his companion, who wheeled toward him at
>   once. “Destroyer droids!”
>
> The younger Jedi nodded, smiling. “**Offhand**, I’d say this mission is
>   past the negotiation stage.”

Quoted from Star Wars Script

What does "**offhand**" mean in the script above?

According to the dictionary,

offhand means 'not ​friendly, and ​showing little ​interest in other ​people in a way that ​seems ​slightly ​rude'.

I don't exactly see how this meaning makes sense in that dialogue.

Does it mean that the younger Jedi regarded destroyer droids' attack rude or unfriendly?

Another possible interpretation is that it means 'done or made without previous thought or preparation', which means the Jedi thought the attack was reckless or rash.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, they've used offhand to mean the latter of the two definitions that you cited. However, you've interpreted the definition wrongly.

What the Jedi means is that it has just occurred to him that this mission is past the negotiation stage, although he has not contemplated or considered that thought in depth or for any length of time. In other words, he spoke that impression as soon as he thought it.

Answer (score 0):

[Offhand](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/offhand_2) (adv)

> - without being able to check something or think about it.

(OLD)